# How to hide the export button in highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm using Angularjs with highcharts-ng library and I want to have a highchart directive with the ability to export the chart (showing the export button) and another without that option (not showing the export button) but I have not managed to disable (hide) the button using the configuration object. How can I do that?

Here is the snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['highcharts-ng']);

app.directive('myChart', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<highchart config="chartConfig"></highchart>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.chartConfig = {
        options: {
          exporting: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-chart></my-chart>    
<div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/0.0.7/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Even if a disable the export property

Comment: do you have js fidlle for the same.

Comment: @strikers yes http://jsfiddle.net/davidbarreto/c2Lj14fq/

Comment: @David How did you solve this?

Comment: @Sajeetharan look at the accepted answer at the bottom, that is how I "solved" it. I could not find a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem, and since the regular options somehow don't work, I just hide it with some CSS and javascript (jQuery) where needed.

```
$('.highcharts-button').css('display': 'none');
```

Comment: I would rather call it a workaround, but I agree though that this should not be the accepted answer. Your solution is, but it's identical to mudhaka's, minus the formatting (why?), but i'll +1 you both, hoping OP would notice.

Answer (score 2):

`var HighChartChartModel = {
        options: {
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },`

This will work

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right way to do this in highcharts-ng:

options: {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },

Note that exporting is at the same level as chart.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a bug in highcharts-ng.

if you simply don't include the `exporting.js` you won't get that button.

a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/24wbnech/1/)

Comment: Yes I realize that, but the problem is that for another directive I need the ability to export the chart. Excluding the file will remove the functionality everywhere in my app.

Comment: Not a bug. see answers above